# c# change file encoding without loading all the file in memory

Tags: c#, file-encodings

I need to change a file's encoding. The method that I've used loads all the file in memory:

```
string DestinationString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(FileName)));
File.WriteAllText(FileName, DestinationString, new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding());
```

This works for smaller files (in case that I want to change the file's encoding to `ASCII`), but it won't be ok with files larger than 2 GB. How to change the encoding without loading all the file's content in memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do so by writing to the *same* file - but you can easily do it to a *different* file, just by reading a chunk of characters at a time in one encoding and writing each chunk in the target encoding.

```
public void RewriteFile(string source, Encoding sourceEncoding,
                        string destination, Encoding destinationEncoding)
{
    using (var reader = File.OpenText(source, sourceEncoding))
    {
        using (var writer = File.CreateText(destination, destinationEncoding))
        {
            char[] buffer = new char[16384];
            int charsRead;
            while ((charsRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, charsRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could always end up with the original filename via renaming, of course.

Comment: Side note: clearly one can change encoding *to* ASCII in place as it is fixed width encoding and requires no more bytes than any other encoding (whether it worth doing is different story)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Potentially, but it would be tricky as the file could end up shrinking. I'd definitely encourage the approach I've suggested here over that.